# Python + selenium download image without extension

Tags: python, image, selenium

I'm using python 3 with selenium, I have to download an image

HTML:

```
<img id="labelImage" name="labelImage" border="0" width="672" height="456" alt="labelImage" src="/shipping/labelAction.handle?method=doGetLabelFromCache&amp;isDecompressRequired=false&amp;utype=null&amp;cacheKey=774242409034SHIPPING_L">
```

Python code:

```
found = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('img[alt="labelImage"]') 
src = found.get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, 'image.png')
```

that image file is empty, if I try to switch extension to html, shows me message below:
"We're sorry, we can't process your request right now. It appears you don't have permission to view this webpage"

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but are you sure that this URL contains an image file at all? For me, it opens a normal website. Can you specify which image you want to download?

Comment: That image will only appers after fill some forms in FedEx website.

Comment: Then I think you should follow the same procedure(filling forms etc.) using selenium in your program.

Comment: my code already do that, i just hav do get that image in the end of process

Comment: Not %100 sure, but you might want to wait for the image to load. In some cases, adding delays using the following helps: `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);` .

Comment: I use code below to get the image

        found = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('img[alt="labelImage"]') 
        src = found.get_attribute('src')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, 'image.png')

but when i open image file, receive following message:

"We're sorry, we can't process your request right now. It appears you don't have permission to view this webpage."

Comment: Please don't put important information in comments. You should edit your question and add the details in there so everyone sees them. The actual code you are using along with the HTML should be added to your question from the start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you recieve when attempt to download comes from the fact the `urllib` call is a brand new session for their server - it does not have the cookies and authentication your browser does. E.g. it is the same as if you open incognito mode in the browser, and paste in the address bar the src attribute - for the server you are a new client, that hasn't fill in the form, logged in, etc.

You may want to try something else - in the selenium/the browser session, taking a screenshot of just the `<img>` element. That op is with variable success, Chrome for instance added support for it only recently, and in some situations it fails:

```
found = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('img[alt="labelImage"]')
try:
    found.screenshot('element.png')
except Exception as ex:  # FIXME: anti-pattern - I don't recall the exact exception - when you run the code, change it to the proper one
    print('The correct exception is {}'.format(ex))
    browser.get_screenshot_as_file('page.png')
```

If taking the element's screenshot fails, you'll get one of the whole page - which you can then trim to the element.